# How can I update and edit across two tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables that I created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE book(id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY, title VARCHAR(256),
book_id INT, author VARCHAR(128), year INT, httplink VARCHAR(256)) ENGINE MyISAM;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE excerpt(id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY, book_id INT, excerpt_title
VARCHAR(256), year INT, measure VARCHAR(256), page VARCHAR(128)) ENGINE MyISAM;
```

So there's a table of books...and a table of excerpts from each book...they're linked by book_id. Each unique book has a book_id...and every excerpt from that book has the same book_id.

Now, I have a php form that allows to users to edit a entry after they've searched for it:

```
<p>Edit Record</p>
<form method="post">
<p>Title:
<input type="text" name="title" value="$n"></p>
<p>Author:
<input type="text" name="author" value="$e"></p>
<p>Year:
<input type="integer" name="year" value="$p"></p>
<p>Mirlyn link:
<input type="text" name="link" value="$l"></p>
<p>Excerpt name:
<input type="text" name="excerpt" value="$ex"></p>
<p>Page numbers
<input type="text" name="page" value="$s"></p>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id">
<p><input type="submit" value="Update"/>
```

When the user hits the edit button next to the link, the following fields autopopulate with the record the user chose to edit: title, author, year.

If the user does not change the title, but changes (or doesn't change) the other fields, what is the correct MySQL statement to update the record? I believe I'd only have to update the 'excerpt' table.

BUT...if the user edits title...how do I manage that? I'd have to check if the title exists in the 'book' table. If it does, I'd have to change the book_id for the excerpt. If it doesn't, I'd have to add it to the 'book' table with a unique book_id and then change the record appropriately in the excerpt table. Help?

Thanks!

Comment: there is no "correct" mysql statement in this case. either you unconditionally update all of the fields (e.g. round-trip the data through the client and hope they don't mess up fields they shouldn't be), or you dynamically build an sql statement to update only the fields you want changed.

Comment: What is your current PHP code?